# Getting error in postgres query No operator matches the given name and argument types

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Reason why code is causing error when `groupHds is null`? I'm getting
this error, groupHds is list of string and ddi.group_hd is string column.

Error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> Position: 586

Query:

```
"SELECT ddo.* FROM dta_delivery_order ddo JOIN dta_current_state dcs ON dcs.entity_id = ddo.id " +
                    " AND dcs.entity_type = 'DeliveryOrder' JOIN dta_order_info_data doid ON doid.entity_id = ddo.customer_order_id " +
                    " AND doid.entity_type = 'CustomerOrder' JOIN dta_do_item ddi ON ddo.id = ddi.order_id " +
                    " WHERE dcs.process_state_code = 'Delivery_ReceiveTask_WaitForContinueAfterDailyTrigger'" +
                    " AND dcs.create_date BETWEEN CAST(CAST(:dateFrom AS TEXT) AS TIMESTAMP) AND CAST(CAST(:dateTo AS TEXT) AS TIMESTAMP) " +
                    " AND (:channelCode is null OR doid.channel_code = CAST(:channelCode AS TEXT)) "  +
                    " AND  (COALESCE(:groupHds) IS NULL OR ddi.group_hd IN (:groupHds) )";
```

Comment: Obvious: you cannot compare a text string and binary data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can u please let me know how can i handle this then

Answer (score 1):

Remove .* and try this :

```
"SELECT ddo FROM dta_delivery_order ddo JOIN dta_current_state dcs ON dcs.entity_id = ddo.id " +
                " AND dcs.entity_type = 'DeliveryOrder' JOIN dta_order_info_data doid ON doid.entity_id = ddo.customer_order_id " +
                " AND doid.entity_type = 'CustomerOrder' JOIN dta_do_item ddi ON ddo.id = ddi.order_id " +
                " WHERE dcs.process_state_code = 'Delivery_ReceiveTask_WaitForContinueAfterDailyTrigger'" +
                " AND dcs.create_date BETWEEN CAST(CAST(:dateFrom AS TEXT) AS TIMESTAMP) AND CAST(CAST(:dateTo AS TEXT) AS TIMESTAMP) " +
                " AND (:channelCode is null OR doid.channel_code = CAST(:channelCode AS TEXT)) "  +
                " AND  (COALESCE(:groupHds) IS NULL OR ddi.group_hd IN (:groupHds) )";
```

Comment: getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the bytea column is a text, try to encode the bytea column to text using `encode` function like this:

`encode(your_table.bytea_column_name, 'escape')`

reference: [PostgreSQL Documentation: Binary String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html)

Comment: Hey Danny can u please let me know how should modify my query, Yes the bytea column is a text

Comment: which column is bytea?

Comment: Hey Danny no coloumn is bytea in my schema

Comment: what about adding `if (groupHds != null) { sql += ' " AND ddi.group_hd IN (:groupHds) )"' }`  ? so only add this filter to the SQL only if groupHds list is not null.

Comment: i am using  jpa in spring boot  with native query so i think this is not possible